# Kafka Version for Java 1.7 with Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, java-7, kafka-consumer-api

I have a application with Java 1.7 . Trying to integrate Kafka but any Kafka version am trying my jetty(6.1.10) server is not running , throwing error Unsupported major.minor version 52.0: Which is the latest version which can support Java 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetty 6 is deprecated / End of Life.

See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

So, before I answer, know that ALL versions of Java 1.7 are now End of Life, Expired, and not suitable for use in production.

If you need Java 1.7 support, use Jetty 9.2.x series, that was the last version of Jetty to support Java 1.7.

But know that even Jetty 9.2.x is End of Life.